# NIFI QueryDatabaes org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: COUNT(*);

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to get the count from MySql Database using ExecuteSQL Processor. However everytime I do that I am getting following error.

**Error:**

> org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: COUNT(*);

Following is the configuration
[image]

If I change the query to select everything it works fine, like below.

> Select * from temp.test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep **alias name** for the count(*) as count or cnt ..etc,

then use the query with alias name for count(`*`) in you execute sql processor.

**Example:-**

```
Select count(*) count from temp.test
```

(or)

```
Select count(*) as count from temp.test
```

Comment: You can also set "Normalize Table/Column Names" to true, that will change funky names, such as the one that comes back from COUNT(*), to something that is valid Avro.